# Erro ao injetar objeto: retornando null

Tags: java, java-ee, cdi

Quando eu injeto um objeto na classe ele retorna `null`, parece que não é instanciado.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fercosmig.util.db.PopulaTabelaUsuario.main(PopulaTabelaUsuario.java:37)
```

`PopulaTabelaUsuario`:

```
public class PopulaTabelaUsuario {

    @Inject
    private static UsuarioRepository ur;

    public PopulaTabelaUsuario(){
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Usuario u1 = new Usuario();
        u1.setNome("Adamastor Teste");
        u1.setEmail("ateste@gmail.com");
        u1.setTipoUsuario(TipoUsuario.USER);
        u1.setUsername("ateste");
        u1.setPassword("ateste");
        ur.inserir(u1); // aqui dá erro.

    }

}
```

`UsuarioRepository`:

```
public class UsuarioRepository implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    public UsuarioRepository(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void inserir(Usuario usuario) {
        Criptografia c = new Criptografia();

        String senha = usuario.getPassword();
        usuario.setPassword(c.criptografiaSha256(senha));
        usuario.setDataCadastro(new Date());
        usuario.setAtivo(true);
        em.persist(usuario);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pra mim não faz muito sentido injetar um objeto statico. Tente mudar private static UsuarioRepository ur, para private UsuarioRepository ur;

Comment: Eu tinha colocado assim, mas o Eclipse, na linha do erro, informa que está errado e sugere que use o static para funcionar: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field ur: Change 'ur' to 'static'.

Comment: Você inicializando a aplicação por um `main` e querendo recuperar uma instância de um contexto CDI inexistente? Espera que a instância de `UsuarioRepository` venha de onde? Se quere usar CDI em um ambiente Java SE, veja como isto deve ser feito. Se tiver algum problema quanto a isto, atualize a pergunta que posso lhe ajudar

Answer (score 1):

O CDI é a especificação do Java EE 6 que cuida da parte de injeção de dependências, e depende de um container Web para sua execução padrão.

Mas você pode utilizar este poderoso recurso do Java EE em um projeto Java SE também. Veja este tutorial de como você pode fazer isto:

http://blog.rocketscience.io/dependency-injection-with-cdi-in-java-se/

A implementação mais famosa do CDI é o Weld:

http://weld.cdi-spec.org/

Há outros projetos que adicionam mais recursos ainda para trabalhar com injeção de dependências, como o DeltaSpike, que podem ser úteis dependendo da sua necessidade.

Espero que isso já possa orientá-lo.